HTTP Auth header
I use this web page to create an auth header to access an API
https://www.debugbear.com/basic-auth-header-generator
It works... but I would prefer not to type a username + password into a webpage, so I looked up how-to-do on the command line and found this webpage
https://docs.alertlogic.com/configure/connections/authorization-header.htm
It also works, but ideally I would like to do this in C, so I set about coding it here on an Arduino.
unsigned char auth[] = "login:password";

unsigned char base64[64];

unsigned int base64_length = encode_base64(auth, strlen((char *) (auth)), base64);

Serial.println(base64_length); 
Serial.println(( char *) base64); 

But this doesn't work? Its very close, almost getting it right until the very end when it returns a different result?
What have I missed?

Well, it's header, so you probably forgot to send its name and no need for length there...

what length does it return and what is the difference?

Its the same length, the difference is in the last six characters in the correct version they are F4MQ== and in the compiled version they are ExAA==. The length returned is 31. The actual length of the login and password is 30 characters. Just tried this with a difference base64 arduino library, that doesn't work either. Same problem.

Library I am using right now is base64_encode by dojyorin 2.0.4. Library I previously tried was Base64 1.0.0. by Aruro Guadalupi.

Can you please share a sample of your login and password?

Erfan, this website tells you how to generate a password using the command line, it works https://docs.alertlogic.com/configure/connections/authorization-header.htm?source=post_page-----a1b82fdcfb5f-------------------------------- I need to match the password produced by whatever login/password you put in here.
